# What configuration needs to be done in OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG for Entity Framework?

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I have created the SharePoint Email Event Receiver for the document library.
In my project, I have used entity framework to insert a record into the database.
But, when I am debugging the application with the OWSTIMER.EXE Its giving me an below error.

> Error: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: you need to add entity framework to Gac in your project